# DX structure : /main/default, but it doesn't have to be right?

Tags: salesforcedx

This [Salesforce official doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm) says:

> Static resources must reside in the /main/default/staticresources directory

Is this an outdated document?

In my understanding, you can put this in your own folder structure, i.e

> /resource-util/sales/staticresources

So long as the containing directory is named `staticresources` right?

Can someone please confirm, this is super confusing @Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't have to be /main/default/staticresources. It does, of course, need to be "staticresources" at the bottom level, but the folder structure is otherwise however you'd like it to be to organize your files.

Comment: thanks @sfdxfox. anyone at Salesforce seeing this, plz fix your doc.